# Query string return url

Tags: angular, iis, angular7

In local process i have in http://localhost the dashboard screen.
If i'm not authenticated angular redirect me to http://localhost/login

If in local I try to reach http://localhost/catalog and i'm not authenticated, I'm redirect to login with "catalog" in query string -> http://localhost:4200/login?returnUrl=%2Fcatalog
So, once logged in, I can go on catalog

Here my problem:

On IIS if i write www.myexample.com/catalog, catalog is cut and I simply arrive in login page.

If I set "Add query string" it still not work, and if in login I refresh the page "?returnUrl=%2" is added more and more times

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That isn't an Angular question but an IIS question. Your server should redirect all incoming requests to the `index.html` file, and Angualr should then manage the redirection through its router. You can also use the [`useHash` strategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles) so that you don't set your server up.

Comment: Server redirect to index.html yet but doesn't work. I can't try for the hash, thanks for the suggest